# Gradle build always fails on different projects

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to build Gradle projects. Installed Gradle's latest version (6.0.1) using Homebrew. When I try `gradle build` in various projects (for example https://github.com/arnabmitra/trustlines-demo), it gives this error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
> org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.<init>(java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver, org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTreeFactory)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
```

Similar errors happened with other projects. It's my first time using Gradle (come from Maven) and what I am trying to do is just compile the project to have `.class` files.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use your installation of gradle. Use `./gradlew`. That will automatically download and use the version of gradle that the project uses, instead of an incompatible version.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Does it download other required libraries, e.g. for compiling Kotlin? `./gradlew` gives an error: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain` and `gradle wrapper` shows `Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt`.

Comment: The problem is that this particular project forgot to version the wrapper jar file in its `gradle/wrapper` directory, thus making it impossible to use the wrapper. The wrapper.properties says they use the version 5.4.1 of gradle, so you could try installing that version and using it. But given they messed up with the jar, maybe 5.4.1 is not the version they expect either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin 1.3.10, update Kotlin to at least 1.3.20.

Issue was that Kotlin 1.3.10 uses the DefaultSourceDirectorySet constructor via reflection which has been removed in Gradle 6: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-defaultsourcedirectoryset-constructor-has-been-deprecated/29610

Comment: Nice. This fixed my problem with an old Kotlin project. 